# Intellij IDEA: How to fix Abnormal build process termination?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a beginner in java. When I try to build simple hello world program on Intellij Idea, it throws an error.
I have tried to reinstall both java JDK and IntelliJ IDEA, but still nothing works. I have no idea why the error occurs and how fix it. Any help will be appreciated!
The full error is as below:

```
    Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=4903591409901567202 -Dfile.encoding=GBK -Duser.language=ru -Duser.country=RU -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2019.3 "-Didea.home.path=D:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/system/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.5 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/system/compile-server/test_42be22cd/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\msalm\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-4294992341525313184-is-running\" -classpath "D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/lib/tools.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-transport-http-1.1.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/netty-common-4.1.41.Final.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/qdox-2.0-M10.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/guava-27.1-jre.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/trove4j.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/httpcore-4.4.12.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/log4j.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/jps-model.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/resources_en.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/util.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/netty-transport-4.1.41.Final.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.41.Final.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-api-1.1.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/httpclient-4.5.10.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-transport-file-1.1.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/annotations.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/asm-all-7.0.1.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/jna.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/netty-codec-4.1.41.Final.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-impl-1.1.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.41.Final.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-util-1.1.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/platform-api.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/jdom.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.1.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-spi-1.1.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/guava-27.1-jre.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.5.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/lib/guava-27.1-jre.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.5.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Users/msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Users/msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:/Users/msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Users/msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/intellij.android.kotlin.extensions.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common-26.5.0.2.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.5.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/repository-26.5.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/sdklib-26.5.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api-26.5.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger-26.5.0.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 65503 80451694-5e68-461a-8a2d-33a3eb9debfc C:/Users/msalm/.IdeaIC2019.3/system/compile-server
Build process started. Classpath: D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/lib/tools.jarSLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:65503; reason: failed to create a child event loop
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:181)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:147)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:179)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 24 more
Exiting.
```

Comment: I notice you are in `Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"`, so maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder) is helpful. It looks like kind of dependency problem, not the build environment.

Comment: So maybe put your dependency file here may help other solve your problem

Comment: @Lebecca Hi, the link you've sent says to add  slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar to the application. I don't really understand to where should I add it? Sorry for such basic question.

Comment: 会说中文吗？你的项目结构是怎样的，有没有什么复杂的东西？如果是个简单的 helloWorld 起不来，结合日志来看，很可能是 idea 自己的问题 `D:/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar`，你可以试试重装

Comment: @Lebecca 大概两周前装的idea, 用了几次都没有问题，结果今天早上不知道为什么就这样了。已经卸载重装过了，现在简单的hello world也起不来。

Comment: 挺不幸的兄弟，你的项目是就只有一个类文件，里面就输出个 helloworld 都不行是吗

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506788/failed-to-create-a-child-event-loop) mentioned something about the firewall, may give it a try.

Comment: 你要学会多用异常堆栈中的 error message 信息来搜索

Comment: 是防火墙的问题，已经好了，谢谢！@Lebecca

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some common firewall trouble using IDEA with windows because it uses localhost communication with compiler process, So check your firewall setting for IDEA and make it full access.

Some reference:

- [Failed to create a child event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506788/failed-to-create-a-child-event-loop)
- [IntelliJ IDEA do conflict with firewall?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001626319-IntelliJ-IDEA-do-conflict-with-firewall-)

Do the record for someone may suffer the same problem.